# Access hive using sparklyr package?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, sparklyr

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
home <- "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", spark_home = home, version = "1.6.2")
readFromSpark <- spark_read_csv(sc, name="test", path ="hdfs://hostname/user/test.csv",header=TRUE)
```

I already successfully access `hdfs` using sparklyr. But how to access hive table/command using `sparklyr` because I need to store this `df` into hive.

Comment: Try with this: `df_tbl <- copy_to(sc, readFromSpark, "yourTableName")`

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel i dont want to put that df as df_tbl. I want to save readFromSpark into hive table, i need to create database,table then i can put readFromSpark into hive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, sparklyr doesn't have the function to create database/table directly. But you can use `DBI` to create database/table.

```
library(DBI)
iris_preview <- dbExecute(sc, "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE...")
```

Comment: Great, but how do you put a `sdf` that's been registered or a `sdf` that's been cached using `tbl_cache` into Hive as the EXTERNAL TABLE that you're suggesting here? I don't see any instructions for creating a table using a local object that `sparklyr` and `dplyr` can manipulate in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try spark_write_table:

```
    spark_write_table(readFromSpark, 
    '<database_name>.readFromSpark', mode = 'overwrite')
```

If you're also creating schema, you can use DBI package:

```
    dbSendQuery(sc,"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS xyz")
    tbl_change_db(sc,"xyz")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieve this:

The setup:

```
cc <- RxSpark(nameNode = hdfs_host(myADL))
rxSetComputeContext(cc)

myXDFname <- 'something'
hivTbl <- RxHiveData(table = myXDFname)

sc <- spark_connect('yarn-client')

tbl_cache(sc, myXDFname)
mytbl <- tbl(sc, myXDFname)
```

Now do something with it

```
mytbl %>% head

mytbl %>% 
   filter(rlike(<txt col>, pattern)) %>%
   group_by(something) %>%
   tally() %>%
   collect() %>% #this is important
   ggplot(., aes(...)) %>%
   geom_triforce(...)
```